# Rails 4 - How to change the s3_direct_upload options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip, assets

In Rails 4, I am using `s3_direct_upload` & `paperclip` gems for file uploads, right now files are uploading directly to `s3` as per the below code

```
attr_accessible :direct_upload_url

has_attached_file :document,
:url => '/cv_uploads/:recruiter_id/:unique_id/:resume_basename.:extension',
:path => "/cv_uploads/:recruiter_id/:unique_id/:resume_basename.:extension",
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3_credentials/public_s3_details.yml",
:s3_permissions => 'public-read'

validates_attachment :document, :presence => true,
:content_type=>{:content_type=>['application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/rtf',
  'application/x-rtf', 'text/rtf', 'text/richtext', 'application/doc', 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document']},
:size => { :less_than =>5.megabytes }
```

With the same model, I need to implement the normal file upload feature also. How can I change this model to which will supports both s3 and normal file uploads?

Comment: You can use carrierwave and you implement both within same model - https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

Comment: Sorry. If I change the gem then it will affect the whole architecture. I have used `s3_direct_upload` related code everywhere. Can you please suggest  a solution with the same gem?

Comment: you want to implement normal file upload for same file attribute or other attribute, column?

Comment: Here `unique_id, direct_upload_url` will cause a issue in normal file uploads but these fields are working as mandatory. How can I update this attributes?